# XSLT Code for multiple line data into single line

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, workday-api

[image: image description here]

As in the picture the address line 1 is in two lines within the field `Address Line-1`.

Example, this is how it is now:

```
Address Line 1: 1234 California street

                   APT 555
```

When I convert this data into XML its splitting the address into two lines. How to bring this address into single line in XSLT ?

After applying XSLT I want this into single line as following

Column/Field Name as **Address Line-1**

Address as **1234 California street APT 555**

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please review the help on how to ask.

Comment: Provide an example of the XML that you are transforming, and an example of the desired output. Chances are that you want to use `normalize-space()` to collapse the carriage return(s) and whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that your source XML has the address split into 2 lines,
maybe with some spaces at the beginning of the 2nd line, something like this:

```
<address>1234 California street
    APT 555</address>
```

So if you either apply an identity template to such a tag or use `<xsl:value-of select="address"/>`, the resulting text will also be divided into 2 lines, **keeping leading spaces in the 2nd line**.

Probably you should use `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(address)"/>`.

*Normalize-space* function will likely do the job, converting a sequence of internal "white" chars into a single space.